# Vertical 3-level dropdown menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have a problem with a vertical css menu with 3-level submenus.The last submenu isn't aligned as it should be and I don't know where's the problem.

Here's a demo http://jsfiddle.net/pPckk/1/
And if You can't open jsfiddle, here's the code:

```
<div id="global-nav">
        <ul class='parent'>
            <li class="smt"><a href="#">cat1</a></li>

            <li class="c1">
                <ul class='child child1'>
                    <li class="smt"><a href="#">cat1.1</a></li>

                    <li class="smt"><a href="#">cat1.2</a></li>

                    <li class="c1">
                        <ul class='child child2'>
                            <li class="smt"><a href="#">cat1.2.1</a></li>

                            <li class="c1">
                                <ul class='child child3'>
                                    <li class="smt"><a href="#">cat1.2.1.1</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="smt"><a href="#">cat1.3</a></li>

                    <li class="smt"><a href="#">cat1.4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="smt"><a href="#">cat2</a></li>

            <li class="c1">
                <ul class='child child1'>
                    <li class="smt"><a href="#">cat2.1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
#nav, #nav ul {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#nav a:link, #nav a:active, #nav a:visited {
    background-color: #333333;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav a:hover {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #333333;
}
#nav li {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}
#nav ul {
    display: none;
    left: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 192px;
    top:0;
}
#nav li ul a {
    float: left;
    width: 192px;
}
#nav ul ul {
    top:0;
}
#nav li ul ul {
    left: 192px;
    top:25px;
    margin: 0 0 0 13px;
}
#nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li li li li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: your fiddle doesn't work for me.

Comment: You can't open the site or the code doesn't work?

Comment: The code doesn't work. The `li` are not expanding.

Comment: Which browser do You use?Chrome? I tested it and it works on IE and Firefox but not in Chrome.

Comment: @lam3r4370 : see my answer... problem solved... I tested in FF and it is working perfect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
#nav li ul ul ul {
    left: 192px;
    top:0px;
    margin: 0 0 0 13px;
}
```

and you are done...

Below is what I have and it is working perfect... Yipee!!! I did it first time and worked!!!

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#nav, #nav ul {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#nav a:link, #nav a:active, #nav a:visited {
    background-color: #333333;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav a:hover {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #333333;
}
#nav li {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}

#nav ul {
    display: none;
    left: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 192px;
    top:0;
}

#nav li ul a {
    float: left;
    width: 192px;
}

#nav ul ul {
    top:0;
}

#nav li ul ul {
    left: 192px;
    top:25px;
    margin: 0 0 0 13px;
}

#nav li ul ul ul {
    left: 192px;
    top:0px;
    margin: 0 0 0 13px;
}


#nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul ul{
    display: none;
}
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li li li li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#">cat1</a><ul class="jaccordion">
<li><a href="#">cat1.1</a><ul class="jaccordion"></ul></li>
<li><a href="#">cat1.2</a><ul class="jaccordion">
<li><a href="#">cat1.2.1</a><ul class="jaccordion">
<li><a href="#">cat1.2.1.1</a><ul class="jaccordion"></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li>
<li><a href="#">cat1.3</a><ul class="jaccordion"></ul></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="#">cat2</a><ul class="jaccordion">
<li><a href="#">cat2.1</a><ul class="jaccordion"></ul></li></ul></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works in FF,IE and Opera but not in Chrome.Where's the problem?

Comment: I don't know much, but I know that some attributes won't work with some browser depending on the compatibility... There are many things that works in FF but no in IE, etc...

I have solved the problem that you had in your code... regarding browser, I'm not sure...

Comment: sorry to say, but I won't be able to help you regarding issue of browser... You might need to ask this as a separate question asking why this is not working...

Comment: I have asked the question why it is not working... will get back to you tomorrow once I get reply... hope this is fine with you...

Comment: @Parkar, Thank You. You are probably testing the code in IE 6 and that's normal because ie6 and lower support hover only on the a tag

Comment: The problem is in `float:left;` :)

Comment: so problem solved now??? Yipeee!! [Question that I asked is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142044/sub-menu-not-working-in-ie-chrome-working-in-ff-opera)

Comment: [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142044/sub-menu-not-working-in-ie-chrome-working-in-ff-opera)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following rule:

```
#nav li ul ul {
    left: 192px;
    top:25px;
    margin: 0 0 0 13px;
}
```

since it not only applies to the second, but also to the third level.
Add a rule for your third level ul to correct that.

I suggest using classes on the uls in such menus: `<ul class="first-level">...`
This allows more precise styling and shortens the selectors.