# Sub-Menu Not Working in IE & Chrome.. Working in FF, Opera

Tags: html, css, menu, submenu

Below is  the code that I am writing in HTML and I'm getting what I want perfectly in FF, Opera. My friend is able to run in IE too but I'm not... Also I am not able to see output Chrome. Any reason??

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#nav, #nav ul {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#nav a:link, #nav a:active, #nav a:visited {
    background-color: #333333;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    visibility: visible;
}

#nav a:hover {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #333333;
}
#nav li {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}

#nav ul {
    display: none;
    left: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 192px;
    top:0;
}

#nav li ul a {
    float: left;
    width: 192px;
}

#nav ul ul {
    top:0;
}

#nav li ul ul {
    left: 192px;
    top:25px;
    margin: 0 0 0 13px;
}

#nav li ul ul ul {
    left: 192px;
    top:0px;
    margin: 0 0 0 13px;
}


#nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul ul{
    display: none;
}
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li li li li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#">cat1</a><ul class="jaccordion">
<li><a href="#">cat1.1</a><ul class="jaccordion"></ul></li>
<li><a href="#">cat1.2</a><ul class="jaccordion">
<li><a href="#">cat1.2.1</a><ul class="jaccordion">
<li><a href="#">cat1.2.1.1</a><ul class="jaccordion"></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li>
<li><a href="#">cat1.3</a><ul class="jaccordion"></ul></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="#">cat2</a><ul class="jaccordion">
<li><a href="#">cat2.1</a><ul class="jaccordion"></ul></li></ul></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you tried anything else yet? If you have no answer yet, I'll post you the solution tomorrow. Writing lotsa text with smartphone sucks;)

Comment: I added the solution ty my answer. Test it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a lot of duplicate styles in your css. Try to eliminate those. Especially the uls have a lot of rules which override each other. Try to use classes for the different levels of your uls to make to rules more specific.

EDIT:

all the css code you need: ([test it](http://jsfiddle.net/euL5e/2/))

```
#nav, #nav ul {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    list-style:none;    /* <- shorthand declaration is enough */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#nav a:link, #nav a:active, #nav a:visited {
    background-color: #333333;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav a:hover {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #333333;
}
#nav li {
    position: relative;
    width: 80px;     /* <- This defines the width, no need to declare elsewhere */
}

#nav ul {
    display: none;
    left: 100%;      /* <- % makes you indepentent of declared with in li*/
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
}

#nav li:hover > ul{
     display:block;  /* <- does all the hovermagic for you, no matter how many ul-levels you have */
}
```

for several reasons, this code wont work in IE 6 (if you need to support it, you need some really nasty workarounds)

Comment: the major problem is that in IE after taking mouse over `cat 1`, sub-menu of `cat1` didn't get displayed...

Answer (score 0):

Part of the issue is that you have not declared a doctype in your HTML.  No declared doctype will put IE into quirksmode and then it behaves differently than what you're expecting.

You're going to want to place `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your document.
[Quirksmode Explanation](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html)

Additionally I think there are a many robust solutions available that will work a little better than yours.  As previously mentioned you have many duplicate styles declared, which is likely also causing you issues.

A quick google search game up with the following solution which works really well.
[CSS3 Dropdown Menu](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/css3-dropdown-menu/)

I did a quick modification of the code there and applied it to yours.  Not sure if this will do exactly what you're looking for, but it's a start.

```
<style>

#nav {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 line-height: 1.5em;
}

#nav li {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

/* main level link */
#nav a:link, #nav a:active, #nav a:visited  {
  background-color: #333333;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  visibility: visible;
}

#nav a:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #333333;
}

/* dropdown */
#nav li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
} 

/* level 2 list */
#nav ul {
  display: none;
  left: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 192px;
  top: 0;
}

#nav ul li {
 float: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

/* clearfix */
#nav:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

#nav {
  display: inline-block;
} 

html[xmlns] #nav {
 display: block;
}

* html #nav {
  height: 1%;
}
</style>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: As far as I can see, your code has some problems. I'll explain it tomorrow.

Comment: `*` hack is valid, but only interpreted by IE6 - since this dropdown-menu wont work in IE6, you can omit it.
`html[xmlns]` is for xhtml - since you use html5 doctype, its useless.
clearfix via `#nav:after` doesn't work in IE 7.
`visibility` in the a-selector is unnecessary.